# Why doesn't my list drop animation not work in Swift

Tags: swift, animation

I have a function in my view controller subclass below which should animate a list drop over 2.5 seconds as a test but its dropping the list immediately

```
    private func animateList() {
        
        if listDropped == false {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.5, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut) {
                self.tableView.isHidden = false
                self.listDropped = true

            } completion: { (finish) in
                print("DEBUG: list drop animation complete")
            }
        }
        else {
            
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.5, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut) {
                self.tableView.isHidden = true
                self.listDropped = false
            } completion: { (finish) in
                print("DEBUG: list raise animation complete")
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tried reading the documentation but I am sure I am implementing the animate method correctly. I just can't see why it isn't animating the list up and down every time I press the drop/raise list button.

Comment: Can you show the declaration of the property `listDropped`?

Comment: ```private var listDropped = false```

Answer (score 0):

For display the animation up and down with UIView animation. You should update tableView's height in place of their visibility.

Please find sample code below:

```
private func animateList() {
        
        if listDropped == false {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.5, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut) {
                var rect = self.tableView.frame
                rect.size.height = 120(or any value)
                self.tableView.frame = rect
                self.listDropped = true
            } completion: { (finish) in
                self.tableView.isHidden = false
                print("DEBUG: list drop animation complete")
            }
        }
        else {
            
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.5, delay: 0.0, options: .curveEaseInOut) {
                var rect = self.tableView.frame
                rect.size.height = 0(or any value)
                self.tableView.frame = rect
                self.listDropped = false
            } completion: { (finish) in
                self.tableView.isHidden = true
                print("DEBUG: list raise animation complete")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but the drop down list isn't showing at all

Comment: Got the list showing up now with a change to the table height but now it is doing something really weird. I click on the button to drop the list and the list appears instantly, not over 2.5 seconds. Then I click again to close the list and the table instantly grows longer by an mount equal to its same height then slowly closes to its original height then instantly closes. Hope you can follow what I'm saying.

Comment: In Place of using[.curveEaseIn, .curveEaseOut, please use [.curveEaseIn, .curveEaseOut].

Comment: thanks I have done that but it is still not animating correctly, it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Are you using auto-layout or frame ?

Comment: I am setting my constraints programmatically so not using auto-layout interface builder

Comment: so update height constraint of table view in animation block and call layoutIfNeeded().